# Does this entity really exist?

Tags: video-games, night-in-the-woods

I recently finished the game *Night in the Woods*, and I am very confused whether

> The murderous Black Goat, which influences a dark cult and drives Mae close to insanity

actually exists or not. TV Tropes is surprisingly firm in their interpretation that this entity does *not* exist and lists various mundane explanations for the alleged supernatural phenomena, from mental health issues to

> hallucinations from fumes in the mines, which are also mentioned in-game.

However, the game provides evidence that the entity *does* exist:

> The Cultists felt positive effects on themselves when sacrificing people, such as feeling younger and the city recovering somewhat. They also mentioned multiple negative things that happened when they failed to sate the goat, such as a Blizzard.

The biggest flaw in these arguments is that they are all provided by the same source. So my question is: Do we have evidence, preferably in-universe, that shows or disproves that this entity exists?

Comment: There is also apparently a cultist who can walk through walls. That said, I do believe there is intentional ambiguity in the game.